# Parsing Freemarker templates with Javascript

Tags: javascript, freemarker

Has anyone parsed Freemarker templates using Javascript or is there any JS library which does this?

I have a bunch of freemarker templates, I call an API which will return JSON data, now I want to parse freemarker template using JS and replace variables with these values.

As there are some iterative blocks and other logic in templates, parsing is not going to be easy if I write own parser in JS.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked for something similar for my projects, but no such thing exists. The idea of a cross-platform templating language is a recent one and the most commonly used one is mustache.js.

Considering that Freemarker replies heavily on Java along with its macros and intricate file inclusions I think this would be a really hard parser to write.

Answer (score 0):

I once did

https://github.com/andyhot/freemarkerjs

Though it doesn't support the full freemarker language, it should be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I came across [armano2/freemarker-parser](https://github.com/armano2/freemarker-parser) on GitHub but this project also doesn't look like it is yet complete.

NOTE: If I were to venture creating such a parser myself I'd probably start with a [PureScript](http://www.purescript.org/) implementation as I'd expect the parsing implementation to be more straight forward and the maturity of related libraries to be better in a functional language.